# Forall constraints

Tags: haskell, equality, type-families

How do I write a `forall` constraint, for example for some type families `F` and `G`:

```
forall x y. G (F x y) ~ (x, y)
```

Is it possible using Edward A. Kmett [`Constraints`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.8) package? And if so could a small example be provided? I presume I need to use `Forall`.

Comment: Are you looking for this to be a constraint of a larger type or do you want the value to actually be that equality? It might help to provide more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you are looking for the value to represent the equality itself, would `equalityVal :: G (F x y) :~: (x, y); equalityVal = ... Refl ...` with `:~:` from `Data.Type.Equality` work? If, on the other hand, it is a constraint on a larger type, can't you just have `G (F x y) ~ (x, y) => ...`? I believe `Forall` from the constraints package is from universally quantifying over constraints (like `(Forall p, p a) => a`) where `p` is can then be a constraint like `Num`, which doesn't seem to be what you're looking for (if I'm understanding correctly).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is possible using `constraints`. Be careful, however! The equality you claim is unlikely to hold with enough generality for `constraints` if the type families are non-trivial. Consider, in particular, whether the type families successfully reduce when `x` and `y` are stuck type families

```
type family X where {}
type family Y where {}
```

Also, I see that your particular desired constraint has no free variables whatsoever. Hopefully, it's just an example; an actual closed constraint like that is unlikely to be useful.

---

The fundamental type family in `Data.Constraint.Forall` is `Forall`. This particular example might be handled a bit more conveniently using `ForallT`, but it's most important to understand how to use `Forall`.

Generally, `Forall p` means `forall x . p x`. That doesn't sound very general, but it actually is, if you build up your `p` step by step. You seek

```
forall x y. G (F x y) ~ (x, y)
```

Start by defining a class expressing the relationship you seek.

```
class G (F x y) ~ (x, y) => C x y
instance G (F x y) ~ (x, y) => C x y
```

Now you can go step by step, defining

```
class Forall (C x) => D x
instance Forall (C x) => D x
```

(which you can read as `D x = forall y . C x y`)

and then using `Forall D` (i.e., `forall x . D x`) to express your constraint. You'll need to use `inst` to get the `Dict (D x)` and again to get the `Dict (C x y)`.